# Android Java - Tracking Multiple Touch Objects/Events?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am an experienced programmer with C++/C# trying to get into the android game design world.
Using Java in Eclipse.

There are a bazillion tutorials on how to move a single object by tracking a touch on an entire screen, but how do i track touch events on many individual objects randomly on screen?

For starters i wanted to write a class that would be instantiated multiple times and held in an arraylist.  Each is drawn to a random position on a fullscreen, SurfaceView.  Easy stuff so far...
But for the life of me i cannot find out how to drag any of these objects around!!

I have an activity that uses a custom view (extends SurfaceView).  Instantiates a GameBoard class that handles game board screen drawing.  the GameBoard class also holds/draws an ArrayList of gameCharacters that draw fine on the screen, but need touch control.

Im at my wits end, any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a top-down shooter (Akari) which doesn't drag the objects around, but uses their location for collision detection.

In my SurfaceView I call theThread.touchEventType(x, y). The thread goes through the objects (in your case, the array), and checks if they match. In the case of a match, it would return a value associated with the object, and all MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVEMENT actions before MotionEvent.ACTION_UP are done on that object.

Hope this helps. If you need any sample code let me know.

Comment: Hrmm, it seems inefficient to iterate all 'touchable' objects to check for collision (or any event)... but it seems to be the way its done in the android world.

Comment: After looking around it seems like this is way to do it. If exact precision is not necessary, I highly recommend using Android's Rect class for detection.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you did. 
My solution was a bit different. I'm trying to write a backammon game. I have 30 objects to place on the screen and move them around. Of course some of them overlap. So my problem was that I touched an object and ended up moving another one (from what I figure it was an object that was placed on the screen after the one I touched and on the left of the one I touched).

Anyway, what I did was create a custom object that extends view and place it on GestureOverlayView. I override the onTouchEvent() and it looks something like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
    int y = (int) event.getRawY();

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (Math.abs(x - this.getX()) < BackgroundView.slotSize && Math.abs(y - this.getY()) < BackgroundView.slotSize) {
                //do whatever I want
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            //break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //this is the dragging part
            this.setX(x - size/2);
            this.setY(y - size/2);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            break;
        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```

From what I read, when I return false, the action is not consumed, so another object can do that. So basicly, no object consumes it until one does by returning true.

I still consider myself a newbie and I think there are better ways to do this, but it works quite well for me. Hope it helps. You or someone else. 
I'm open for new suggestions.